# Pivot Table Error 56901 non-constant expression

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to create a pivot table of average salary in `Division_ID` as Row and `Job_ID` as Column using data in `employees2` table. So far I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT Division_ID, Salary, Job_ID
FROM Employees2
)
PIVOT (
AVG(Salary) FOR Job_ID IN (ENG, TEC, MGR)
)
ORDER BY Job_ID
```

I get the error, "non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values"

What am I doing wrong? Most the examples I can find online deal with Numerical values after the IN statement, do I need to do something different since im working with text/string?

Comment: Job_ID is varchar isnt it? Put them in single quotes. `Job_ID IN ('ENG', 'TEC', 'MGR')`

Answer (score 6):

Use below Query.

```
SELECT *    FROM (
    SELECT Division_ID, Salary, Job_ID
    FROM Employees2
)  
PIVOT 
(
     AVG(Salary) FOR Job_ID IN 
    ('ENG', 'TEC', 'MGR')     ------------> Change done here.....
)
ORDER BY Job_ID
```

The values `ENG`, `TEC` and `MGR` need to be surrounded by single quotes to be considered as constant values.